# How to add a title attribute from a different field to a link produced by a view

Tags: views, 8, navigation

I have a view that uses one field to produce a list of links to content.

I want to add a 'title' attribute to the link produced by the view that takes its value from a different field.

How does one do this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to zhilevan for pointing me in the right direction. After much trial and error this is the only thing I got to work other than completely rewriting the input with custom html.

1. I needed to add a "path to content" field. Note my fields are called 'field_heading' and 'title' respectively.

[image]

Note: the field that will actually host the link has to be **at the bottom** of the list. I wasted ages trying to figure out why I couldn't target my title text before realising this...

2. You need to uncheck "Link to content" in the setting for the host field - in my case 'Heading'

[image]

3. In the 'Rewrite output' section you need to actually provide a link or it will not work - or at least I could not get it to work without it. So the 'path' field I added earlier was used here as the path for the link. I could then add title field to the title attribute. You can see the available replacement patterns in the drop down with that name.

[image]

and the title attribute override...

[image]

Anyhoo, that was what i had to do to get it to work. Hopefully it is useful to someone else. I would love to see a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using   views `Rewrite results` feature, Rewrite your Link with checking `Override the output of this field with custom text` and put your markup there and with Replacement patterns put your title as  your link attribute title.

More details Provided by @Raf

Thanks to zhilevan for pointing me in the right direction. After much trial and error this is the only thing I got to work other than completely rewriting the input with custom html.

1. I needed to add a "path to content" field. Note my fields are called 'field_heading' and 'title' respectively.

[image]

Note: the field that will actually host the link has to be **at the bottom** of the list. I wasted ages trying to figure out why I couldn't target my title text before realising this...

2. You need to uncheck "Link to content" in the setting for the host field - in my case 'Heading'

[image]

3. In the 'Rewrite output' section you need to actually provide a link or it will not work - or at least I could not get it to work without it. So the 'path' field I added earlier was used here as the path for the link. I could then add title field to the title attribute. You can see the available replacement patterns in the drop down with that name.

[image]

and the title attribute override...

[image]

Anyhoo, that was what i had to do to get it to work. Hopefully it is useful to someone else. I would love to see a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Do you mind pointing me to an example? Rewrite seems to be doing nothing for me when I try edit the title field.

Comment: @raf you're welcome, sorry for late answer I was away.

Comment: @raf because your answer is the same of mine remove this answer please. I add the details provided by you to my answer.